# How to open URL having POST request method in WebView in Windows Store App

Tags: windows-8, webview, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I need to open some URL in `WebView` from the source code of an another URL. I am getting source code of that URL via `ScriptNotify` event. That URL contains a `<form />` with GET/POST request & parameters

The HTML can contain either this

```
<form id="pay" method="GET" target="_blank" action="https://xxxxx.com/qqq/www">
    <input type="hidden" value="643" name="param1">
    <input type="hidden" value="313.62" name="param2">
    <input type="hidden" value="GZc6PFXOTfmY58yJyk3DTg==" name="param3">
</form>
```

Or this

```
<form id="pay" method="POST" target="_blank" action="https://xxxxx.com/qqq/www">
    <input type="hidden" value="643" name="param1">
    <input type="hidden" value="313.62" name="param2">
    <input type="hidden" value="GZc6PFXOTfmY58yJyk3DTg==" name="param3">
</form>
```

Now if I have GET method then I can develop URL by parsing the source code, it will become this for our example. I can open in `WebView`

https://xxxxx.com/qqq/www/?param1=643&param2=313.62&param3=GZc6PFXOTfmY58yJyk3DTg==

How can I do same if there's POST request ?

Comment: Is there a reason to not use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` or similar framework class to send a get/POST request, instead of using WebView for api invocation?

Comment: I just don't want to get HTTP response. I am using WebView because the POST request open some form, user will fill that form.

Answer (score 2):

There's no method on `WebView` allowing you to perform a POST request. You could do it by invoking a JavaScript function inside `WebView`, though. First you need to construct a web page containg the form you require and a JavaScript function submitting it:

```
var html =
    @"<html>
        <head>
            <script type=""text/javascript"">
                function Submit() 
                { 
                    document.getElementById('pay').submit(); 
                } 
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form id=""pay"" method=""POST"" action=""https://xxxxx.com/qqq/www"">
                <input type=""hidden"" value=""643"" name=""param1"">
                <input type=""hidden"" value=""313.62"" name=""param2"">
                <input type=""hidden"" value=""GZc6PFXOTfmY58yJyk3DTg=="" name=""param3"">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>";
```

You then navigate to this HTML string and invoke the function:

```
webView.NavigateToString(html);
webView.InvokeScript("Submit", null);
```

During tests the second call always executed before the page was actually loaded and failed because of that so I had to work around it by reacting to `LoadCompleted` event:

```
webView.LoadCompleted += WebViewOnLoadCompleted;
webView.NavigateToString(html);

private void WebViewOnLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs navigationEventArgs)
{
    webView.LoadCompleted -= WebViewOnLoadCompleted;
    webView.InvokeScript("Submit", null);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible without modifying webpage with javascript ?

Comment: @Xyroid I don't know of a way.